# Singular or plural verb after "my experience in X, along with Y,..."

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

Singular or plural?

Would it be "make" or "makes" in this case:

> I believe my experience in program management and evaluation, along with my Master’s degree in Sociology with a specialization in migration, makes/make me an ideal candidate for this position.

Comment: makes would be the right word

Comment: You can replace *my experience in program management and evaluation, along with my Master’s degree in Sociology with a specialization in migration* with third person "it".

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**: "*Makes*" would be correct.

---

The word "**makes**" is correct in this context, as you are using it to describe an *uncountable* noun (experience) and, separately, a *countable singular* noun (degree).

Answer (score 0):

“Makes” is correct because the commas after “evaluation” and  “migration” are bracket commas.  The sentence must still be grammatically correct if you remove them and the words between them.